# MariaDb 10.1 Master-Slave lost or not syncro

Tags: mysql, mariadb, master-slave

I've a system with Master-Slave based on MariaDB 10.1

After down master server, I stop slave, and put sites, to use slave how dbhost.

```
Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Last_Errno: 0
Last_Error:
```

What is my surprise that when going to use the slave server, stop the master-slave model, while the master computer restarted, the difference between the data was **1 hour.**

This is a mistake? This is common? The Master-Slave model is a chimera? There's something I've done wrong?

Comment: I don't understand "and put sites, to use slave how dbhost".  Can you give the commands you performed?

Comment: Mysql.host --> Master Localhost -> slave. on config sites, work with dbhost = mysql.host . Put site to use slave, on localhost, stop slave, cahnge dbhost to localhost.

Comment: mysql replication is full of surprises. In fact, they are not carry out real data sync, but actually just rerun some crud in the slave. If you use any CRUD that involve mysql/mariadb time date command, be prepare for surprises if both master and slave timezone and time not sync. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-timezone.html